# Setting margins from browser window

Tags: html, css, margin

So, i need to make my website inside a container which would have 30px margins from browser window from all sides like so: http://i58.tinypic.com/1ik8xg.png .

So far i have these styles on my elements:

```css
body, html {
   height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
   height: 100%;
   border:1px solid black;
   margin-left:30px;
   margin-right:30px;
   margin-top:30px;
   margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

But in this case i get a y-scroll bar and my #wrap container ends up to big in height. My last example had problems when resizing browser window..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calc` to calculate 100% - 60px. Note that this will not work on IE8 and Opera Mini. I guess you can set `height: 100%` first, followed by the rule using `calc`. That should set a default for the few browsers that don't support calc.

```css
body, html {
   height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
   height: calc(100% - 60px);
   border:1px solid black;
   margin-left:30px;
   margin-right:30px;
   margin-top:30px;
   margin-bottom:30px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">Hello</div>
```

Another approach using position: absolute.
Also note the removal of padding and margin on html and body. This seems to eliminate the scrollbar too.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! It works. Second problem is, that i get a y-scroll bar and i dont need it on my website at all, so i'm gonna just add overflow-y:hidden; to my html, body css. And i'll hope that it wont get me any problems in future))

Comment: I've added a second approach. The scrollbar seems to be caused by the default padding on the body, so setting it to 0 eliminates the scrollbar in the second snippet. This doesn't work in the first one, but your approach of using `overflow-y:hidden;` should work too, as long as the whole page fits in the window.

Comment: Thanks again man! I liked your second approach and gonna use it. It's even more simple then your first one and those paddings and margins on body, html i dont need too.